# WPF ListView.ItemContainerStyle Presses All ListViewItem Elements Together

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, styling

This is what my original ListView looked like:

[image: Original ListView]

Note that the ListView is inside a Grid column (if you want the view's full XAML, I'll edit the post later).  Here is the ListView's XAML:

```
<ListView Name="Worklist" Margin="5 2 5 5" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="275" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{StaticResource AppBackground}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding WorklistIndex}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" Margin="3 5 3 5" CornerRadius="8" Padding="4" >
                <StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SampleName}" FontSize="16" Margin="0 0 0 5" />
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SampleID}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I add a ListView.ItemContainerStyle section, the elements in the ListViewItem get compressed:

[image: Styled ListView]

```
<ListView Name="Worklist" Margin="5 2 5 5" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="275" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{StaticResource AppBackground}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding WorklistIndex}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" Margin="3 5 3 5" CornerRadius="8" Padding="4" >
                <StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SampleName}" FontSize="16" Margin="0 0 0 5" />
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SampleID}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

What can I do to allow the ListViewItem to stretch the entire width of the Grid column but maintain the fade-in animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ListView` definition, set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`.

```
<ListView 
  Name="Worklist" 
  Margin="5 2 5 5" 
  BorderBrush="Transparent" 
  Width="275" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
  Background="{StaticResource AppBackground}" 
  SelectedIndex="{Binding WorklistIndex}">
...
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve the problem.  I also tried to assign it to Stretch as a Setter under the ListView.ItemContainerStyle section.  This also did not work.

Comment: Just solved it.  I had to remove the HorizontalAlignment = "Left" setting, but keep the HorizontalContentAlignment setting.  Thanks again.